# PHP Mysql query gets extremely slow after adding another WHERE parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I have been googling for a while about this issue, but couldn't find a solution.
I have a `query` that is gathering information from a `mysql` `database` and whenever I had this to the query: `"date = {$this->datum->format('Y-m-d')}"` it takes around 5 seconds to finish. When I don't use this `parameter` it is just taking a few milli seconds.

Anyone knows what is causing this `issue`?

Comment: Maybe add some Indexes in database for the field You are using where?

Comment: check whether your tables are indexed. means it should have an id columns as a primary key, unique key, index or fulltext

Comment: @Coold My tables have a unique id which are primary keys.

Comment: "Anyone knows what is causing this issue?" i have tried it in my SQL but i cant explain it http://imgur.com/xzgWTBJ . only the Network differs. try to use a tool called "heidiSQL" and try ur querys multiple times to check what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an index :

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
 ON table_name (`date`)
```

Comment: What does an index exactly do? And does it apply to a table or a column?

Comment: We can say it indexes the column of the table, to relate it or search it faster.